# macdeployqt seems not work correctly

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, macdeployqt

I am currently trying to deploy my Qt5.8 app on MacOs. A latest Travis job is [here](https://travis-ci.org/tamlok/vnote/jobs/210583080). I got the `VNote.dmg` file after using `macdeployqt`. Then I copied it to another MacOS and tried to run it, but got the following error:

```
/Applications/VNote/VNote.app/Contents/MacOS/VNote ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore
  Referenced from: /Applications/VNote/VNote.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout
```

Then I used `otool -L /Applications/VNote.app/Contents/MacOS/VNote` to get the output:

```
/Applications/VNote.app/Contents/MacOS/VNote:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWebChannel.framework/Versions/5/QtWebChannel (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtPositioning.framework/Versions/5/QtPositioning (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
```

Then `otool -L /Applications/VNote.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets` shows:

```
/Applications/VNote.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtWebChannel.framework/Versions/5/QtWebChannel (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtPositioning.framework/Versions/5/QtPositioning (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.8.0_1/lib/QtQuickWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickWidgets (compatibility version 5.8.0, current version 5.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
```

The `QtWebEngineWidgets` seems to still reference the absolute path on the Travis env.

What should I do to deploy a Qt App? Thanks very much!

Comment: You state you're trying to deploy a Qt 5.7 app, but the reference of the cellar library refers to 5.8. Do you have two versions of Qt on your build machine, which is getting confused?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Sorry for the confusion. I use Qt5.7 for local development while the Travis uses Qt5.8. It could build the target out, so I think Qt5.8 could build the Qt5.7 app, right?

Comment: I believe that's you're problem; macdeployqt is being called from the 5.7 Qt framework and looks to resolve paths for 5.7 libraries. The 5.8 Qt library will be ignored, so you need to treat it as [a 3rd party library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780602/automatically-include-qt-libraries-in-the-app-bundle-deploying-on-mac/18781575#18781575), use *install_name_tool* and do it yourself. A better solution would be to upgrade your own code to use 5.8.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Nope! I don't think 5.7 or 5.8 matters. `macdeployqt` does not change the path of the frameworks. Someone has posted a tool to fix this [macdeployqtfix](https://github.com/aurelien-rainone/macdeployqtfix.git). Thanks very much!

Comment: *does not change the path...* - that's the point of [macdeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html). It copies the required Qt frameworks into the app bundle and fixes up the paths. Before calling `macdeployqt`, the paths refer to the installed Qt frameworks; after calling `macdeployqt` you can see they've been rewritten as  `@executable_path/../Frameworks...`

Comment: @TheDarkKnight But `macdeployqt` **forgot** to change the path of the dependencies of `/Applications/VNote.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets`, which causes the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the bug of `macdeployqt`. It seems to not fix the dependency of all the frameworks. Instead, it just  fix the direct dependencies of the executable.

Thanks to [macdeployqtfix](https://github.com/aurelien-rainone/macdeployqtfix.git), which is a tool to do all the things `macdeployqt` forgot.

By the way, if your app uses `QWebEngineWidget`, you need to `macdeployqt` the helper `QWebEngineProcess` bundle, too.