# How to build QT Project from terminal MacOS X

Tags: qt

For example, lets take a default QT widget application that we get. So instead of using QT Creator if we want to build using the terminal then what is the way to do that?

Basically we want to produce the build for the project which actually also contains the `dmg` file.

Compile output when done using QT Creator shown is below when no change is done :

```
14:37:04: Running steps for project QTDefaultProj...
14:37:04: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:37:04: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
14:37:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
14:37:05: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Compile Output after changing the directory :

```
15:31:50: Running steps for project QTDefaultProj...
15:31:50: Starting: "/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/qmake" /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/QTDefaultProj/QTDefaultProj.pro -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug
Info: creating stash file /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDefaultProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Debug-2/.qmake.stash
15:31:50: The process "/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/qmake" exited normally.
15:31:50: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for `qmake_all'.
15:31:51: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
15:31:51: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/uic ../QTDefaultProj/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../QTDefaultProj -I. -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib -o main.o ../QTDefaultProj/main.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../QTDefaultProj -I. -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib -o mainwindow.o ../QTDefaultProj/mainwindow.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -dM -E -o moc_predefs.h ../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/mkspecs/features/data/dummy.cpp
/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/moc -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include ./moc_predefs.h -I/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/QTDefaultProj -I/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include -F/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib ../QTDefaultProj/mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../QTDefaultProj -I. -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I../../ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/Frameworks -Wl,-rpath,/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib -o QTDefaultProj.app/Contents/MacOS/QTDefaultProj main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -F/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/lib -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
15:31:55: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
15:31:55: Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

Comment: In the directory of the project file (.pro) call `qmake` and then `make`. Or are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Just `qmake` and `make` or de we need to add something extra also?

Comment: That will build the app, assuming the project file is correct. If you want to deploy the app, you'll need to call [macdeployqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780602/automatically-include-qt-libraries-in-the-app-bundle-deploying-on-mac/18781575#18781575)

Comment: If you do it once with Qt Creator, you can check the executed commands in the _Compile Output_ window.

Comment: @m7913d I have edited with the compile output, but running `/usr/bin/make` gives `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Running `qmake` gives the following error : `Could not find qmake configuration file macx-clang.
Error processing project file: /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/QTDefaultProj/QTDefaultProj.pro`

Comment: You should run it in the build directory specified in _Projects > Build > General > Build directory_

Comment: @m7913d That path directory is created only when we build once using QT Creator, so if someone is building the project for the first time it will not show that directory from terminal. So how to do?
Also running `/usr/bin/make/` gives following results : `make: Nothing to be done for first'.`

Comment: That is because the compiler has nothing to do. Nothing changed since the last compilation. You can change the build directory and Qt Creator will show you how to start from empty.

Comment: @m7913d But how to build when the build file is not created, as in when first time build has not happened using QT Creator?

Comment: Qt will start from scratch when you change the build directory. Just create the build folder and execute the same commands as Qt Creator.

Comment: @m7913d I think I was not clear. I meant, when we execute the command /usr/bin/make we go inside the build directory which is created after building through QT once. 
But how will we run when we want without QT Creator as in without building through qt creator once?

Comment: You was very clear, but maybe I wasn't: Just create the build folder yourself, i.e. create an empty folder where you want the build output of your program.

Comment: @m7913d But how will an empty folder work without any make file or anything. And running /usr/bin/make doesn't make sense also as the project is in some other folder so there should be some way to link between two.

Running /usr/bin/make fails in an empty folder.

Comment: Qt will first run qmake, check the compile output after you changed the build directory.

Comment: @m7913d I have edited the question with the compile output, can you please have a look, as I don't see any qmake command, and also for make I am seeing the same message but somehow at the end a few operations are being performed.

Comment: @m7913d Okay I am able to generate the project. Here I have to use qmake full path, may be that is why I was not able to generate.

Comment: @m7913d Written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from [m7913d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7621674/m7913d) I am finally able to build the QT project from terminal without using QT Creator.

So steps are :

- Create an empty folder name it as `build-debug` for example.
- Inside your `build-debug` folder run the following command :

  ```
  pathToQTDirectory/QT/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/qmake pathToQTProjectFolder/MyProject/
  /usr/bin/make qmake_all
  /usr/bin/make
  ```

If the above doesn't work then try seeing in the QT Creator compiler output the steps involved when you specify a new directory as the build directory.